# how to make a video from shaderlight rendered images?

Tags: animation, video, rendering, sketchup

I am using sketch up pro for creating a model and animation. and shader light for rendering the scenes. but Shader light is saving all the rendered images into 1 folder. I would like to create a video from those rendered images. Do I have to use another software for that?

please help.

Comment: Yes, If your tool doesn't allow you to create images you will have to use some other software to create videos

Comment: @Rakshi - can you pls name some gud software for same.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasa. You have a option to create video from selected images.

Please consider accepting the answer and also share your email.

Rakshith,

Comment: Why share email for spam bots to pick up?

Comment: @Rakshi -I am  sorry, but in Picasa the scenes will come one after the other ,  however i wanted to create flash video with quick motion between the scenes .

Comment: @sona Okay, Please let me know if you come up with some solution

Comment: @Rakshi - Those rendered images can be converted into moving picture or animation with the help of movie maker software.i have used movie maker software, n its working fine for me.